# Magento 2.4: How to add fixed tier pricing for bundle products?

Tags: magento2, admin, tierprice, group-price

I can see Magento 2 doesn't offer native support for fixed-tier pricing for bundle products.

I want to know 2 things:

1. Why this fixed pricing option is not there in the core module?
2. How can we achieve the solution to set a fixed tier price for bundle
   products?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Magento offers built-in support for both fixed price and range prices.

The price of a bundle product is based on **Bundle Items**.

- If you have multiple products available for a Bundle Item, the product price will be displayed as a range since it will vary depending on the customer's selection.
- If you have only one product for each Bundle Item, the product price will be displayed as a **fixed price**. In this case, customers won't have the option to choose different bundle options and will need to purchase the fixed option.
  [image]

You may need to review the functionality of each product type in order to choose the correct one that you need.

1. **Bundle products**

- Bundle products allow you to create customizable products by combining multiple simple products into a single offering.
- This product type is ideal **for situations where customers can choose different options or customize their purchases**, such as configurable options for clothing or electronics.
- With bundle products, **you can define different price options based on the selected options, giving your customers flexibility and control**.

2. **Grouped** product

- Grouped products, on the other hand, **are used to showcase related items that customers can purchase together as a group**.
- This product type is suitable when you want to **sell multiple products as a set,** like a camera kit with accessories or a furniture set with multiple pieces.
- Customers can easily select and add specific items from the grouped product page to their cart, making it convenient for them to **purchase related items in a single transaction**.

Here are some scenarios to help you choose the correct product type:

1. Scenario 1: Offering customizable product options with different prices:

In this case, using a **bundle product** is the way to go. You can define various options (e.g., colors, sizes, add-ons) and set different prices for each combination.

2. Scenario 2: Selling related items as a set or package:

If you want to offer customers the option to buy related items together, a **grouped product** would be suitable. Customers can see all associated products on one page and add them to their cart individually.

Comment: Hi, could you please guide me: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/371379/82670

Comment: Hi @Msquare. I'd love to assist you with that implementation, but currently, I'm unable to research it due to other commitments. However, you could consider opening a bounty to attract others who can provide you with guidance.