# Magento 2.4 How to implement BfCache

Tags: magento2, module, cache, google

I want to implement BFCache into Magento but did not find the proper resources for implementing it using a custom module.

BFCache Reference link : https://web.dev/articles/bfcache

**Can anyone guide me on how to do it?**